# Pull javascript code from tag using js or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, extract

How would I retrieve the javascript call in the anchor tag below in JS or JQuery?  Basically I want to get the code ("javascript:do_my_function('blah', 'string1', 1);") retrieved so I can execute it.  This anchor is embedded several deep in some div tags as well.

```
<a onmouseout="swapImage('btn1','','http://img2.comp.com/img/buttons/btn_g.png',1)" onmousedown="swapImage('btn1','','http://img2.comp.com/img/buttons/btn_g_d.png',1)" onmouseover="swapImage('btn1','','http://img2.comp.com/img/buttons/btn_g_a.png',1)" href="javascript:do_my_function('blah', 'string1', 1);">
<img id="btn1" width="180" height="60" alt="" src="http://img2.comp.com/img/buttons/btn_ge.png"/>
</a>
```

Comment: You should probably look into using css for the image swapping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To retrieve it just use:

```
 var href = document.getElementById('btn1').parentNode.href;
```

That just finds the `img` by id, and grabs its parent, the `a` tag in question.

To call it, you can use:

```
 window.location = href;
```

Or you could parse it and `eval()` it. All of this is highly unconventional by the way. Do you not have any further control over the code?

Comment: The first part seems to work where I assign the href value to a variable.  However, I have to strip out the leading "javascript:" string.  The strange thing is that the eval(href) works when I execute it from the console in firebug but when I try to execute it in JS from the actual rendered page, I get an "undefined function" error.  Doing the "window.location" fails because it seems it is trying to navigate to the JS function.  I don't want to navigate away, just call the function.

Answer (score 0):

To do it with jQuery you can do

```
var jscript = $('#btn1').parent().attr('href');
eval(jscript);
```

This is not a recommended way to do things. Changing the html would be much better